# Postgres distinct case statement with window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, distinct-values

I'm looking to use a case statement that will return the number 1 once for each unique ID  that I have listed and a 0 if the ID is the same as the one above it. The column is a text column that currently either has 'N' or 'Y'.

Below is an example of what my data looks like.  I'd like to keep it as short as possible because this will be used within other SQL.

The SQL: `select case when Value = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end`

Returns:

```
ID      Value
48719   Y      -- returns 1
48719   Y      -- returns 1
48719   Y      -- returns 1 
55555   Y      -- returns 1
```

What'd I'd like to see.

```
ID      Value
48719   Y      -- return 1
48719   Y      -- return 0
48719   Y      -- return 0
55555   Y      -- return 1
```

**Edit**:

This is also a possible scenario. For the first ID, I'd like to have any of the three rows return a 1, but the other two to show 0. Since the case statement would return a 0 for the first row, I can I have it select only one 1 for all rows with that ID.

```
ID      Value
48719   N      -- returns 1
48719   Y      -- returns 0
48719   Y      -- returns 0 
55555   Y      -- returns 1
```

Comment: You are assuming a particular order to the rows, yet SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Do you have a separate column that specifies the ordering of the rows?

Comment: No, and that's my problem. I was going to calculate the row number use that to select, but it's not always going to be the same row that needs to be selected. Therefore, I just want to show 1 once for each unique ID.

Comment: In that case, @ClodoaldoNeto's solution should do what you want.  You need to add an `order by` clause to it, so it would read in part `partition by id order by id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id, value,
    (
        row_number() over(partition by id) = 1
    )::integer as returned_value
from t
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have also shown one other possibility.

Comment: @user3780646 I edited the answer. But I do not understand what the `value` column has to do with the problem.